# Accuracy error between Trimble RTK and Juniper Geode GPSS systems

Tags: coordinate-system, point, gps

I have set up a system for surveying points with a Juniper Geode GPSS because the survey team is too busy to do it themselves. There is a consistent shift to the northeast of the coordinates I am surveying with the GPSS vs what the surveyors got with their Trimble RTK system. The coordinates have good precision but a consistent problem with accuracy.

I am using an app called MapIt on Android to collect the coordinates. The coordinate system is NAD83 in UTM.

Is there a way to eliminate this consistent northeast shift? Is there a way to post process the data easily, or is there a coordinate system problem? I am not a surveyor so I've had trouble even setting the GPS up.

Comment: How much is the offset? It could be the difference between "WGS84" and NAD83 (2011) which is about a meter depending on location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Geode (when receiving WAAS correction) outputting a position based  on ITRF2000, which has a different origin than NAD83, so it sounds like a translation error. MapIt should be transforming the data to NAD83 UTM, but it may be outputting current epoch, and the RTK survey reference may be in a different epoch, which would show a shift.